# How to check if a std::map contains a key that satisfies a predicate

Tags: c++, c++17, std, stdmap

In C++, say you have a `std::map<int,int>` - how would you use `stl` algorithms/libraries to find if there is a `key` that satisfies a certain predicate, e.g. finding if there is a `key` that is an odd number. So far I've got:

```
auto variable = std::find_if(my_map.begin(),my_map.end(), [](const auto& element) -> bool {return element%2 == 1;})
if (variable == my_map.end() .....
```

But how do I make sure the parameter in the predicate function is actually the key?

Comment: Maybe with `element.first`

Comment: Consider using `std::any_of` instead of `std::find_if` if you just want to know _if_ there is a key (not what key).

Comment: Sure you only want positive keys?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the key via `element.first` like this

```
const auto variable = std::find_if(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), [](const auto& element) {
      return element.first % 2 == 1; 
   }
);

if (variable != my_map.end()
{
   // found
}
```

Comment: on line 2 is it element->first or element.first?

Comment: Why don't you try to compile this yourself, see if `element.first` compiles, and you'll be able to figure it out all by yourself!

Comment: @user11508332 since `auto` here is `std::pair<const key, value>`, yes it is `element.first`.

Comment: Beware of that this solution is only valid from C++14, because you use generic lambda. 
If you use C++11, replace `auto` with `std::pair<int, int>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the `pair`-based iterator abstraction when using a range-based for loop with structured bindings. This is generally quite readable, although handling the not-found case adds some noise.

```
std::optional<int> result;

for (const auto& [key, value] : my_map)
   if (key % 2 == 1) {
       result = value; // or key
       break;
   }

if (result)
    /* ... */ ;
```

Using `<algorithm>` seems more idiomatic, though. On the other hand, linear traversal of a `std::map` is non-idiomatic anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Element is a pair, you can access its key with `element.first`. But to access `variable`, as an iterator you may use `->` instead.

```
int main(){
  std::map<int,int> my_map;

  my_map[6] = 12;
  my_map[9] = 18;
  my_map[12] = 24;

  auto variable = std::find_if(my_map.begin(),my_map.end(), [](const auto& element) -> bool {return element.first%2 == 1;});
  if (variable != my_map.end()){
    std::cout << variable->first << " " << variable->second << "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:
`9 18`

Comment: Do not need to use the map's `operator[]` there, simply init-list all the entries `my_map{{6, 120}, {9,18}, {12, 24}};`. Also don't do [using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @MyClass I deleted `using namespace std`, but I think there is nothing wrong with `operator[]`, is just an example